# Function can't get the right variable

Tags: javascript, angular

if "iPhone" be clicked, will turn blue color

and can be toggle. use `this.betState[selectId] = !this.betState[selectId];`

and click "delete" also can cancel the blue color of "iPhone"

Now the problem is "delete" is not working.

I think is because del() get the wrong variable(this.betState)

but betThis() can get the right variable. so toogle is work.

How to fix it?

why del() cannot get the right variable?

**bet.ts**

```
  betState = {};


  betThis(selectId){
    this.betState[selectId] = !this.betState[selectId];
    console.log(this.betState)
  }

  del(id){
    this.betState[id] = false
    console.log(this.betState)
  }
```

**bet.html**

```
  <div (click)="del('o123')">delete</div>
```

**cs.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let list of test">
  <div class="a" (click)="betComponent.betThis(list.test1.qq2[0])" [class.blue]="betComponent.betState[list.test1.qq2[0]]">
        {{list.test1.qq2[1]}}
    </div>
</ng-container>

<app-bet></app-bet>
```

app.compontent.html

```
<app-cs [test]="test" [betState]="betComponent.betState"></app-cs>
```

**data**

```
 test = [
    {
      "test1": {
            "qq2": ["o123", "iPhone"],
          },
    }
  ]
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxlqqj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use child component (bet.component) to parent component (cs.component) communication using @Output decorator.

In cs.component.html , use *ngIf directive to delete the 'iPhone'. This can be handled by declaring a variable which hide 'iPhone' via clicking on 'delete' which is further handled using @Output.

Comment: Not very understanding, can you modify my demo?

Comment: What you mentioned is the key point. I understood it after reading the doc.